# Python Scrapy Charset utf-8

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy

I have a scrapy code that scrapes a website and writes to MySQL. Currently I have problems with the encoding.

*Code part from spider*

```
 def parse(self, response):
    items=response.css('div.footer__unit')   

    for bricks in response.css('div.shop-item'):  
        l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
        l.add_css('title', 'a.shop-item-title::text')
        l.add_css('price', 'div.shop-item-price[param1*="7"] 
        span.price::text')

    yield l.load_item()
```

*pipeline.py*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import mysql.connector
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
import sys
class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
def process_item(self, item, spider): 
    self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='localhost',
                          database='spider',
                          charset='utf8')
    #connecting
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor() 
    addMaterial=("INSERT INTO material "
           "(title, price) "
           "VALUES (%s, %s)")
    #each item to MYSQL
    for x in range (0,len(item['title'])): 
        title=item['title'][x]
        title=title.encode('utf-8')
        price=item['price'][x]
        price=price.encode('utf-8')
        dataMaterial = (title,price)
        self.cursor.execute(addMaterial,dataMaterial)

    self.conn.commit()
    self.conn.close()
    self.cursor.close()
    return item
```

[But when writing to the database, the encoding is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNrmx.png)

My question is how should I fix encoding.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.encode('utf-8')` lines?

Comment: nothing changes

Comment: What program are you using to display the contents of your database? Is it configured to properly handle unicode?

Comment: I using PhpMyAdmin. I need work with data at utf-8.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread the question You were right. It's problem with configuration. Thank you!